Particular case of $H/K$ abelian implies $AH/AK$ abelian involving the ascending central series
Notation and Definitions
Let $G$ be a group. We define $\zeta_0(G) = 1$, $\zeta_1(G)=Z(G)$, and $\zeta_{i+1}(G)/\zeta_i(G) = Z(G/\zeta_i(G))$.
Question
While reading the following proof in Chapter 6 of Kargapolov and Merzljakov's Fundamentals of the Theory of Groups, I failed to understand the bolded parts:

16.2.5. Theorem Let $G$ be a nilpotent group. If $A$ is a subgroup such that $A[G, G]=G$, then $A=G$.

Proof. Suppose on the contrary that $A\not= G$. Write $A_i = A\zeta_i G$, $i =0, 1, 2, ...$; clearly $A_i \unlhd A_{i+1}$. Suppose $n$ is such that $A_n < G$, $A_{n+1} = G$. Since the quotient $A_{n+1}/A_n$ is abelian we have $[G, G] \leq A_n$, whence $A[G, G] \leq A_n < G$, a contradiction.


My attempt
Each quotient $\zeta_{i+1}(G)/\zeta_i(G)$ is abelian by definition. I don't get whether or not this is supposed to imply $A_{n+1}/A_n = A\zeta_{i+1}(G)/A\zeta_i(G)$ is abelian? Is it a homomorphic image of the former quotient or something? It doesn't seem this is the way to go.

Small question, how can you define you sequence of groups by a property on the quotient is it a pullback? Maybe it was already defined before ? I’m probably missing something

@julio_es_sui_glace I mean $\zeta_{i+1}(G)=f^{-1}(Z(G/\zeta_i(G))$, where $f$ is the natural projection from $G$ into $G/\zeta_i(G)$.

Yeah ok it makes sense

Proposition. Let $G$ be a group, let $N_1\leq N_2$ be normal subgroups of $G$, and let $H$ be any subgroup of $G$. Then $\frac{HN_2}{HN_1}$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $\frac{N_2}{N_1}$.
Proof. Define $f\colon\frac{N_2}{N_1} \to \frac{HN_2}{HN_1}$ by $f(xN_1) =  x(HN_1)$. This is well defined: if $xN_1=yN_1$, then $y^{-1}x\in N_1\leq HN_1$, so $xHN_1 = yHN_1$.  It is easily seen to be a homomorphism.
And it is surjective: given $hxHN_1$ with $h\in H$ and $x\in N_2$, we have
$$hx(HN_1) = (hx)(h^{-1}H)N_1 = (hxh^{-1})HN_1.$$
But $hxh^{-1}\in N_2$, because $N_2\triangleleft G$, so $hx(HN_1) = f(hxh^{-1}N_1)$.
Thus, $\frac{HN_2}{HN_1}$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $\frac{N_2}{N_1}$, as claimed. $\Box$
Here, we have $N_1=\zeta_{n}(G)$, $N_2=\zeta_{n+1}(G)$, and $H=A$. Since $A_{n+1}/A_n$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $\zeta_{n+1}(G)/\zeta_n(G)$, which is abelian, it follows that $A_{n+1}/A_n$ is itself abelian.

Missed that, thank you.
